# Storyboard not updating visually

Tags: xcode, xcode9

The problem I'm having is that my storyboard stopped showing changes on the views. The changes that don't reflect are changing constraints, changing views attributes or adding new views to any view controller.

I have tried quitting Xcode, Restarting my Macbook and unhooking my external monitor; but haven't had luck with any of those.

Thank you

Comment: That did it! You saved me @matt thanks! Could you answer the question, so I can accept the answer for future readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes Xcode gets "wedged", displaying an old version of your project and failing to update properly. It might help to clear out the Derived Data and Caches as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994).

Comment: Stopped updating again and the previous fixed stopped working

Comment: Xcode was lagging also in other projects. I ended up deleting it reinstalling it, and that has worked for now @matt